# How to choose a "good" 3.3 V LDO and FET for low power applications?

Tags: low-power, ldo, fet

I am trying to design my first low-power PCB using an ESP32 to switch a 12 V 1.2 A LED Strip.

I purchased this module that charges a Lithium battery using a solar panel [here](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Solar_Power_Manager_5V_SKU__DFR0559). Hence that is where the 5 V comes from. The 12 V comes from boosting the 5 V out of the module.

My two questions are:

1. How do I choose the 3.3 V LDO for maximum efficiency?

I decided to with the [SPX3819M5-L-3-3/TR](https://www.digikey.co.za/en/products/detail/maxlinear-inc/SPX3819M5-L-3-3-TR/2472394). It has a Quiescent Current of 8 µA, what other stuff do I need to consider when deciding?

2. How do I choose the FET M1 for maximum efficiency?

Do I look at the Rds(ON) only or are there other stuff to take into account?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fglKIx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fatVng.png)</sup>

Comment: hm, the efficiency of the LDO won't matter much if you have 100Ω in series with your LED strip – that will burn far more power. Also, I'm not even sure what the idea behind R2 and M1 is – effectively there's only two settings here: M1 is "off", hence the all current flow from 12V through R2 to LED_strip+, burning most energy in R2. Or, M1 is "on", then (nearly) all current flows through R2, M1, directly to ground, burning *all* energy in R2. So, errr… is that really the intended use case? Always having a high power consumption, even higher when the LEDs are off? that does seem a bit surprising

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was supposed to add that R2 to represent the LED strip as a load. I forgot to change its location of it. So basically that R2 is not supposed to be there.

Comment: Any linear regulator is going to have pretty close to the same efficiency here. If you're at all concerned about efficiency, use a switching regulator.

Comment: @JoeyB ah! That makes sense. Why switch the LED strip this way, instead of just toggling the "enable" of the boost regulator?

Comment: @MarcusMüller hmmmmm  did not think of that. Well that PSU Boost does not have an EN pin. Just has Vin+ Vin- Vout+ and Vout-

Comment: that might be something worth investigating further! (maybe you've got a module that just doesn't add an external contact to the enable pin of the central boost regulator IC?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller the boost converter I am using is this: https://www.diyelectronics.co.za/store/switch-mode-modules/381-dc-dc-boost-3a-30v-lm2587.html . It uses a LM2587 IC which has no Remote on/off pin

Comment: Your MOSFETs are drawn upside down.

Answer (score 3):

The LDO will have to dissipate almost 0.45W nominal with a 260mA load (not including the dissipation due to Iq). It will be more if the 5V supply happens to be at the higher end of the tolerance range. That's a bit much for an SOT23 to be safe even with an ideal sea of copper around it. The DFN8 package is more reasonable, particularly with a good thermal connection to the exposed pad and a fair bit of copper around it.

You're also wasting 14mW in R1 when the LED strip is off. Increasing it will reduce static dissipation but runs the risk of the MOSFET dying during turn-on when it might be dissipating several watts for a time while switching, depending on the internals of the LED strip.

In general "maximum efficiency" is not a good goal. You can almost always increase efficiency (or any other parameter) by throwing money and parts at it.

The static (when not switching) "on" power dissipation in the MOSFET is governed by Rds(on) with 12V Vgs. Once it's small enough that the MOSFET runs cool, further increases have limited benefit and add to cost etc., since almost all the power dissipation will be in the LED strip. More efficient LEDs would yield much higher returns.

Does the Iq of the regulator actually matter in this application? It *might* if you plan on putting the MCU to sleep and it's a battery powered application. If it's powered off of the mains, the difference between 8uA and 5mA Iq is often not a big concern. Nor does it matter if it's an LDO or not. There's a fixed 1.7V drop (nominal) required, which is not exactly low.

Comment: What is static dissipation?

Comment: @JoeyB  static (when not switching) There is dissipation when 'on', when 'off' and whilst switching.  Switching 'on' is a rougher situation for the MOSFET  with this circuit because it's slow.

Comment: I think I will just use Edit 2 for now. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: It should be okay if the LED strip does not have any capacitors. Probably close to 4A drawn from the 5V rail. The relay will use a few hundred mW too.

Comment: How did you get 4A

Comment: @JoeyB ~1.2A * 12/5 * 1/0.8 (80% efficiency of the DC-DC)